# jpa persist() function giving error in TABLE_PER_TENANT (multi_schema) multi-tenant strategy

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi-tenant web app with "Shared Database/Separate Schemas" approach using java, jpa(eclipselink), mysql. My persistence file looks like:

```
    <persistence-unit name="GroupBuilderPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
            <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
            <properties>
                <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?"/>
                <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
<--- Here goes other properties definition -->
        </persistence-unit>
```

Now here is my EntityMangerFactory and EntityManager:

```
emfForTenant = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("GroupBuilderPU");
EntityManager em = emfForTenant.createEntityManager();
        em.setProperty("eclipselink.tenant-id", schemaNameAsTenantId);
```

I've an Entity MaterialUnit:

```
@Entity
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(type = TenantTableDiscriminatorType.SCHEMA, contextProperty = PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
public class MaterialUnit implements Serializable {
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 128)
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String unitName;
```

Now the operation is giving error:

```
MaterialUnit mu = new MaterialUnit();
mu.setUnitName("New Unit");
em.persist(mu);
```

The error is:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
Error Code: 1046
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, SEQ_GEN]
Query: ValueReadQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
Severe:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
Error Code: 1046
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [50, SEQ_GEN]
Query: ValueReadQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="SELECT SEQ_COUNT FROM SEQUENCE WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
```

So how will this persist operation work?
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated :)

Comment: logic would suggest that if you have a different schema for each tenant then you have a different EMF for each tenant. If you're saying that EclipseLink supports this with one EMF, then look at their docs for HOW you define it

Comment: Can you suggest any resource or any doc for that pls?

Comment: Errm, the documentation for EclipseLink. If you have chosen that implementation then you ought to be able to find the documentation for the software you use

Answer (score 0):

The error said that there is no database selected..

I think your problem is in this line:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?"
```

when it executes, it connect to mysql but cannot know what schema you need... if you want to have more than one schema (persistent unit), I recommend that create as many persistent units as you need, something like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitONE" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema1"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnitTWO" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema2"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and then call the unit you need by changing this line:

```
emfForTenant = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnitONE");
emfForTenant = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnitTWO");
```

Comment: In a multi-schema strategy there might be hundreds of schema (each tenant represent its own schema), then adding a persistence unit for each schema (tenant) wont be a efficient solution :). Isn't it?

Comment: Well, in that case you have to pass the schema name in the line `<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?`... otherwise it will not work

Comment: But you cant change the persistence.xml after the deployment once done. Or is there any way to do so?

Comment: jeje, honestly I don't have a clue if that's possible... but that is where your problem is... jeje